# ¿Como mostrar un resultado de Jquery cuando no es global?

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema desarrolle una función que me muestra la diferencia de días que existen entre dos fechas, esto desde un datepicker, la operación la resuelve correctamente cuando se muestra en un `alert();`, pero no cuando la muestro en input mediante el método `text();` ya que no me muestra el resultado como en el `alert();`.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

Jquery:

```
let diferenciaFehas;
let fechaPrimera;
let fechaSegunda;
let textoSlider1 = $('#valorSlider1');


$(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: false,
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
        minDate: new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4)),
        maxDate: "+1M",
        onSelect: function (date) {
            let d = new Date();

            let month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            let day = d.getDate();

            let output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
                (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
                (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
            fechaPrimera = moment(output);
            fechaSegunda = moment(date);
            diferenciaFehas = fechaSegunda.diff(fechaPrimera, 'days') + ' Dias';
            textoSlider1.text(diferenciaFehas);
        },
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!---Calendario -->
        <div id="datepicker" class="calendarioPrinipal"></div>
        <!---Fin del Calendario -->
        <div class="rangoActivo1">
            <input type="range" min="4" max="30" id="valorSlider1" value="1" class="slider" />
        </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.min.js" integrity="sha256-3Oy0S9Ym2MLkd1JJRzf4yyp7TN9WUByjhtLj7fBFGKM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando los campos los cuales se quiere mostrar un resultado son campos de tipo `<input>` se usa la función `val()` y no la función `text()`